# Trouble with Parent/Child in OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl

I am currently using C code in Codeblocks for OpenGL and I am having trouble making objects operating independently. In my case I have separate fingers and each one seems to be reliant on the previous finger coding and I cannot seem to figure out why exactly. I think I have gone wrong with my Push and Pop but not sure where. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the important part of the code

```
glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glPushMatrix();

glTranslatef(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glRotatef((GLfloat) shoulder, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glTranslatef(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glPushMatrix();
glScalef(2.0, 0.4, 1.0);
glutWireCube(1.0);
glPopMatrix();

glTranslatef(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glRotatef((GLfloat) elbow, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glTranslatef(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glPushMatrix();
glScalef(2.0, 0.4, 1.0);
glutWireCube(1.0);
glPopMatrix();

glTranslatef (1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glRotatef ((GLfloat) finger, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glTranslatef (0.25, 0.0, 0.0);
glPushMatrix();
glScalef(0.5, 0.1, 0.1);
glutSolidCube(1.0);
glPopMatrix();

glTranslatef (0.25, 0.0, 0.0);
glRotatef ((GLfloat) fingerjoint, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glTranslatef (0.25, 0.0, 0.0);
glPushMatrix();
glScalef(0.5, 0.1, 0.1);
glutSolidCube(1.0);
glPopMatrix();

//need to make finger2 not reliant on fingerjoint
glTranslatef (-0.75, 0.0, 0.0);
glRotatef ((GLfloat) finger2, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glTranslatef (0.25, 0.0, 0.25);
glPushMatrix();
glScalef(0.5, 0.1, 0.1);
glutWireCube(1.0);
glPopMatrix();

glTranslatef (0.25, 0.0, 0.0);
glRotatef ((GLfloat) finger2joint, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glTranslatef (0.25, 0.0, 0.0);
glPushMatrix();
glScalef(0.5, 0.1, 0.1);
glutWireCube(1.0);
glPopMatrix();

//need to make finger3 not reliant on previous fingerjoints
glTranslatef (-0.75, 0.0, 0.0);
glRotatef ((GLfloat) finger3, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glTranslatef (0.25, 0.0, -0.5);
glPushMatrix();
glScalef(0.5, 0.1, 0.1);
glutWireCube(1.0);
glPopMatrix();

glTranslatef (0.25, 0.0, 0.0);
glRotatef ((GLfloat) finger3joint, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glTranslatef (0.25, 0.0, 0.0);
glPushMatrix();
glScalef(0.5, 0.1, 0.1);
glutWireCube(1.0);
glPopMatrix();

glPopMatrix();
glutSwapBuffers();
```

Comment: you didn't undo the first finger translation and rotation before drawing the second finger, so what did you expect? but for some reason, you did undo the scale

Comment: Can you please give me an example

Comment: not without writing your code for you. Look up how glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix work